# Windows 8 support d3d8.dll?

Tags: windows, dll, windows-8

I'd like to ask you guys if Windows 8 support `d3d8.dll` file?
I've heard the Windows 8 renders graphics different than any other version of windows.
Thus making the `d3d8.dll` useless to Windows 8 and causing a crash when running a game.

This is due to Windows 8 having touch screen capability.

Is that true and if so how I will be able to fix it for my game since I need `d3d8.dll` to fix the "CPU speedhack" but in same time I want to have it compatible with all Windows versions.

Comment: Are you copying that DLL from one system to another?

Comment: I will just paste this d3d8.dll in my game client folder. And it works but I am not sure if it will work on Windows 8 and it might cause crash. I can't test at the moment. That's why I am asking if Windows 8 support it.

Comment: Since d3d8 is for DirectX 8. I'd like to know if Windows 8 supports DirectX 8

Comment: Er, don't copy those DLLs around like that. Against the license and liable to fail. If you want to know whether or not Win8 supports DX8, why not ask that? That seems to be the question, so just ask it.

Comment: It's a d3d8 proxy DLL. I hope you get what I meant. So, let me know if it will work properly on Windows 8 for DirectX8 3D calls since I've specified that Windows 8 renders graphic different than other windows versions.

Comment: If you want to know whether or not your program works on Windows 8, you could test it on Windows 8.

Comment: Yeah, but I just found out that it doesn want to run on windows 7 starter. I'll need something like that probably - http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/649749-post1.html

Answer (score 2):

Windows support for specific service or feature is more complex than offering or not offering certain DLL, so the question is incorrect in first place.

If your application is using something, which is missing in Windows 8, you need to identify what it is exactly and fix it on your game side by e.g. removing static link to missing functionality, or using an alternate API for this specific need.

No you cannot copy Windows core DLLs between system just for the purpose of "fixing" your app, without breaching in the same time Windows license agreements.

Comment: d3d8 fixes a bug in my game "CPU speedhack". It works on XP and Win7 but I am asking if it will work on Windows 8 or there are some limitations ? That's all. If there are no limitations and if it doesnt work that means it's because of something other not the file itself. So, let me know please.

Comment: It's a d3d8 proxy DLL. I hope you get what I meant. So, let me know if it will work properly on Windows 8 for DirectX8 3D calls since I've specified that Windows 8 renders graphic different than other windows versions.

Comment: Windows 8 comes with `D3D8.DLL`, but it does not have to confirm that your hack is still in good standing: APIs are available or not, not specific DLLs which might get changed without notice, provided that APIs still work as documented.

Comment: In first place I'd like to stop this bug "CPU speedhack". And it's not mine. :) So, I still dont get it ... will d3d8 DLL Proxy work on Windows 8 since it comes with D3D8.dll file as  you said ?

Comment: The file presence alone does not give you any guarantee, esp. for a hack that you don't even take a trouble to well define, and provide code for.

Comment: I just tested this d8d3.dll on windows 7 and it doesnt allow to run my game client.exe ... when i start it .. it gives an error. Dangg! I believe that I wont use it